# Preserving bounds after orientation change

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using a map with Google Api V3 and I am managing both events window.resize and window.orientationchange for tablets.
Whatever I do in the map like zooming or else but having in that moment certain bounds, if I rotate tablet it goes like a total mess losing zoom and bounds so I would ask you simply how it would be best way to preserve bounds and be at same center+zoom after rotate ?

Thanks in advance to all!

Cheers!
Luigi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind, I solved it by myself just adding:

```
currentCenter = map.getCenter();
currentZoom = map.getZoom();
```

in orientationchange's event then setting back them on resize event and it worked to me :-)

Thanks anyway! 
Cheers
Luigi